# .htaccess file has no effect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I have read about 10 different articles explaining how to write an .htaccess file.  I've followed their explanations and put the .htaccess.txt file in the root directory. But still it won't redirect my site from non-www to www.

Here's my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mecoder.co.il$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mecoder.co.il/$1 [L,R=301]

<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|png)$">
Header set Cache-Control "public, max-age=321408000"
</FilesMatch>


<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault A86400

<FilesMatch "\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg\png|flv|pdf|swf|mov|mp3|wmv|ppt)$">
  ExpiresDefault A1814400
  Header append Cache-Control "public"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(xml|txt|html)$">
 ExpiresDefault A259200
 Header append Cache-Control "proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(js|css)$>
 ExpiresDefault A10800
 Header append Cache-Control "proxy-revalidate"
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\.(php|cgi|pl)$">
 ExpiresDefault A0
 Header set Cache-Control "no-store, no-cache, must revalidate, max-age=0"
 Header set Pragma "no-cache"
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|html|htm|php|xml)$">
 SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
</IfModule>

<FilesMatch "\.(ico|pdf|flv|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)(\.gz)?$">
 Header unset ETag
 FileETag None
</FilesMatch>
```

And here is my [site](http://mecoder.co.il)

Comment: Is your `.htaccess` named `.htaccess.txt`?

Comment: You should remove `.txt`. The file should be just `.htaccess`

Comment: yes, it is named .htaccess.txt

Comment: Just rename it to `.htaccess`, in Linux: `mv .htaccess.txt .htaccess` and it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's not .htaccess.txt but .htaccess (without .txt).

If that doesn't work, you must check if overriding with .htaccess file is enabled in your server configuration. To do that, you should add `AllowOverride All` to your vhost or apache configuration.

Comment: thanks, it does make an effect. But now it is generating a 500 error page

Comment: That means that your .htaccess file has errors. Try with something simplier in htaccess.